# Setting innerHTML for a map element

Tags: javascript, html

I've been banging my head on this one for a while now. At on point it was working (though I might have just imagined it).

This is a basic (or supposed to be) use of the map element with polygon area elements. The map's area elements should be added to the map after the rest of the document loads.  This is done with javascript so the number of areas (wedges of a circle) can be changed easily, as well as the radius of the circle.

```
//test.html body (points.js is included in head)

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x600" usemap="#graphMap">
<map name="graphMap"></map>
<script>
    getPoints();
</script>

//points.js

function getX(radius, angle, num) {
  return Math.round(radius * Math.sin(angle * (i) * Math.PI / 180) + 298);
};

function getY(radius, angle, num) {
  return Math.round(radius * Math.cos(angle * (i) * Math.PI / 180) + 298);
};

function changePointColor(index) {
  var points = document.getElementsByClassName('point');

  var style = points[index].getAttribute("style");
  style = style + 'background-color:green;';
  points[index].setAttribute("style", style);
};

function getPoints() {
  var wedges = 12.0;
  var radius = 300.0;
  var angle = 360.0 / wedges;

  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var map = document.getElementsByName('graphMap')[0];

  var out_points = [];
  var in_points = [];

  for (i = 0; i < wedges; i++) {
    out_points.push(
        [
          getX((radius + 10), angle, i), 
          getY((radius + 10), angle, i) 
        ]
        );

    in_points.push(
        [
          getX((radius - 100), angle, i), 
          getY((radius - 100), angle, i) 
        ]
        );
  }

  for (i = 0; i < wedges; i++) { (function(i) {
    body.innerHTML +=  '<div class="point" style="top:' + out_points[i][1] + 'px;left:' + out_points[i][0] + 'px;background-color:blue;"></div>';
    body.innerHTML +=  '<div class="point" style="top:' + in_points[i][1] + 'px;left:' + in_points[i][0] + 'px;background-color:blue;"></div>';
    var mapHTML = '<area shape="poly" coords="'; 
    mapHTML += out_points[i].join() + ','; 
    mapHTML += out_points[(i+1) % wedges].join() + ','; 
    mapHTML += in_points[(i+1) % wedges].join() + ','; 
    mapHTML += in_points[i].join() + '" href="#" ';
    mapHTML += 'alt="wedge' + i + '" title="wedge' + i + '"'
    mapHTML += ' onclick="changePointColor(' + i + ')"' 
    mapHTML += '>' + "\n";
    map.innerHTML += mapHTML;
  })(i);}

  console.log(map)
  console.log(map.innerHTML);
};
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbAL4/1/).

The problem seems to be that the innerHTML of the map remains unchanged after getPoints() is run. I log the innerHTML of the map element at the end of the getPoints() function:

```
// console.log(map.innerHTML) output

<area shape="poly" coords="298,608,453,566,398,471,298,498" href="#" alt="wedge0" title="wedge0" onclick="changePointColor(0)">
<area shape="poly" coords="453,566,566,453,471,398,398,471" href="#" alt="wedge1" title="wedge1" onclick="changePointColor(1)">
<area shape="poly" coords="566,453,608,298,498,298,471,398" href="#" alt="wedge2" title="wedge2" onclick="changePointColor(2)">
<area shape="poly" coords="608,298,566,143,471,198,498,298" href="#" alt="wedge3" title="wedge3" onclick="changePointColor(3)">
<area shape="poly" coords="566,143,453,30,398,125,471,198" href="#" alt="wedge4" title="wedge4" onclick="changePointColor(4)">
<area shape="poly" coords="453,30,298,-12,298,98,398,125" href="#" alt="wedge5" title="wedge5" onclick="changePointColor(5)">
<area shape="poly" coords="298,-12,143,30,198,125,298,98" href="#" alt="wedge6" title="wedge6" onclick="changePointColor(6)">
<area shape="poly" coords="143,30,30,143,125,198,198,125" href="#" alt="wedge7" title="wedge7" onclick="changePointColor(7)">
<area shape="poly" coords="30,143,-12,298,98,298,125,198" href="#" alt="wedge8" title="wedge8" onclick="changePointColor(8)">
<area shape="poly" coords="-12,298,30,453,125,398,98,298" href="#" alt="wedge9" title="wedge9" onclick="changePointColor(9)">
<area shape="poly" coords="30,453,143,566,198,471,125,398" href="#" alt="wedge10" title="wedge10" onclick="changePointColor(10)">
<area shape="poly" coords="143,566,298,608,298,498,198,471" href="#" alt="wedge11" title="wedge11" onclick="changePointColor(11)">
```

Really at my wits ends on this one. I suppose I've made an obvious javascript or html faux pas. Looking forward to learning my mistake.

Comment: Interesting. It seems strange though, because even if the divs were covering the map, why shouldn't the area elements have been added to the map innerHTML? Maybe something with commenting out the points allowed this to work..not sure. p.s. noted about id. most of the documentation I've seen on map seems old..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append html to the body using `innerHtml` it is re-writeing the html so the map object you got no longer exists  which is why the map areas are not being appended.  (It has been overwritten with the new html - the += means it gets the current html adds your new html and then overwrites the existing html with the new html it has created so your map object is no longer there).

You will need to either get the map object each time you do an `innerHtml +=`

[like in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/823mN/3/)

or append the divs like this:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
//add attributes and styles to div here
body.appendChild(elem);
```

[Example using appendChild](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/823mN/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes down to how buggy the implementation is for image maps in modern browsers. It's quite an old technology (in terms of the life of the HTML syntax), and it's not really used much anymore.

From what I can tell having run that particular JSFiddle in chrome, modifying the `map` element in the page is causing the browser to create a clone of the node, on which it sets the inner HTML. You can tell, since the `map` element which you are logging is not the same `map` element which is in the DOM tree. It has no parent node, and no offset parent.

At a guess, I'd say that this is deliberate behaviour in chrome, to get around having to implement the logic required in the renderer to make the image map dynamically editable.

The solution, unfortunately, may be to try to manually replicate the behaviour of the image map with transparent `div` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't even think that something like that could happen. I think that map is pretty good though, in this case at least it is very useful.  I got around the cloning problem by just creating the whole map element and then appending it as a child to the body.

Comment: @jphager2 How is this the answer?  It is completely wrong - Image map is still part of HTML 5 so all modern browsers will be able to use them - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#image-maps-0

Comment: Ah, fair point, Pete is right, the original `map` element is no longer in the DOM tree because of the innerHTML being overwritten, nothing to do with image map incompatibility. May want to change accepted answer if that's possible